# Removing or fixing Infinality install

Tags: nvidia, kde, fonts

I tried setting up Infinality on my system.  Ever since I changed its settings to the Windows 7 font settings the system has been extremely slow.  Ubuntu is running slow on KDE Plasma Workspace, and Xubuntu. I'll try out the other environments on this machine to see if they're affected as well.

**EDIT:**

I've managed to remove Infinality with:

```
sudo apt-get purge fontconfig-infinality
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa
```

The system still runs slow on all of the installed Ubuntu desktop environments.  I did boot into windows as well and noticed a slow down after first logging in; but that goes away after a couple of seconds. Could it be a graphics driver issue?

The device drivers listed in the terminal for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660 Ti are:

```
driver   : nvidia-331-updates - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-331 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-304-updates - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Is having more than one driver on the system possibly causing this issue?  How could I debug to figure out which package is causing slow down in Ubuntu?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do *for now...*

If you don't know what a PPA is or need some guidance about rolling forward and backward of driver versions  after reading their page, leave a comment below.